# svd to reduce text matricies

Tags: python, preprocessing, dimensionality-reduction

I am having problems with very big texts.

after preprocessing each of my docs represented as a matrix of sentences, where each sentence represented as encoded words (each word have a unique vocab value that represent it).

I have two types of docs, some are very big and some are very small.
so in the end there is two types of matrices :
***let x1 be matrices of MxN and x2 be matrices of m x n , I want to take all the x1 matrices and make to then dim reduction from M*N to m*n is it possible? and if so how?***

I am working with python and ***I wanted to do it with svd, the problem is that I only have managed to do reduction of N to n , but could not reduce the rows.

---

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Fyi if you know how to reduce the number of columns you could always do it in two steps: 1) reduce the columns 2) reduce the columns on the transpose matrix of the result, and then transpose back to get your fully reduced matrix.

Comment: Yes, actually I thought about this after posting , thanks!